# how to block windows jenkins HTTP URL access( http://hostname:8080 ) so that i can use only HTTPS via https://jenkins.domain.com

Tags: windows, jenkins, redirect, https

I have installed Jenkins in windows

I can access Jenkins with two URLs

http://hostname:8080,
https://jenkins.domain.com

how can I block access via HTTP so that everyone can use only via HTTPS

Ps: HTTPS already configured

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `httpPort` to `-1`

See the docs here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/#configuring-http

Comment: The Https configured based on http URL
Requirement is all the traffic should go via Https URL